# Is there a better way to get the intersection of two Observables using RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

Using RxJava, I have one source Observable that emits a number of items that I am looking to intersect with another Observable that emits the same type.  After working through a number of options, it would seem that that the most coherent way to structure things would be this:

```
Observable<String> source = ...emits 20 items

Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    source
        .buffer(5)
        .subscribe(things -> {
            tocheck.getMatches(things) //emits 3 matches
                .subscribe(subscriber::onNext, subscriber::onError, () -> {});
        }, subscriber::onError, subscriber::onCompleted));
```

The expected output here would be that when I subscribe to the resulting Observable, I get 12 items emitted.  It is a requirement that I buffer results due to the contract of getMatches.

On it's face this seems like would work but it does not seem like the cleanest way.  Filter doesn't seem to apply here because I cannot run the intersect check on every item for performance reasons.  I toyed around with using flatMap but the getMatches observable completes the stream instead of the completion notification coming from the source observable.

Is there a better way to structure this?

Edit:
To clarify what was happening with this style of code:

```
Observable<String> source = ...emits 20 items

source
    .buffer(5)
    .flatMap(this::getMatches);  //final observable would emit a total of 12 items
```

This is clearly way cleaner, but when I add some logging (assuming the same data sizes as the original snippet:

```
source
    .doOnEach(notification -> {
        log.trace("Processing {}", notification.getValue());
    })
    .buffer(5)
    .flatMap(this::getMatches)
    .doOnEach(notification -> {
        log.trace("Processing after match {}", notification.getValue());
    });
```

I get 20 instances of the "Processing" log, then strangely only a few log lines from the "Processing after" (when I would expect 12).  It seems to be calling an on complete earlier than it should be.  Maybe I'm structuring something wrong?

Comment: I don't fully understand how `flatMap` completes the stream in your case. May be the problem is in `getMatches` implementation? Can you show some code for it?

Comment: If I'm understanding flatMap, it uses the onComplete from the destination observable. In this case, getMatches says its complete when its done checking for matches on those 5 items, thus completing the stream at only 3 items instead of 12.  Am I incorrect in my understanding there?

Comment: `flatMap` shouldn't propagate `onComplete` from its individual observables, otherwise it wouldn't make sense as an operator. So, in my opinion, something as simple as: `source.buffer(5)
        .flatMap(things -> getMatches(things))
        .subscribe(/* do something to filtered results */);` should work.

Comment: Ran some test and I've updated the post to explain my results. I'm doing my best to extract my real world code into this example code. Is there something incorrect about my usage?

Comment: From what I can see, everything seems fine. Perhaps, some strange magic is happening inside `getMatches()`? It doesn't throw runtime exceptions by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like AndroidEx was spot on. I am using the Redis Lettuce reactive API and it doesn't look like it is behaving appropriately.  The added code snippet from above is the correct way to structure an intersection of two Observables.